# Is there a way to distinguish between two strings that are the same except for different upper and lowercase letters in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, string, uppercase, lowercase

I have a java program that I made that will create a 5 digit string and add it to a mysql database. The strings that are generated will be every combination of the numbers 1-9 the letters a-z and A-Z like

00000
...
00009
0000a
...
0000z
0000A
...
0000Z
00010
...
00019

and so on

My problem is when adding these values to the database it will not add 0000A because 0000a is already in there

for example if I

```
INSERT INTO `mytable`(`mycolumn`) VALUES ("00000");

INSERT INTO `mytable`(`mycolumn`) VALUES ("0000a");

INSERT INTO `mytable`(`mycolumn`) VALUES ("0000A");
```

the only values that appear in my database are 00000 and 0000a

Is there anyway to have mysql make this distinction between the two so I can have strings that appear unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql strings are [case sensitive by default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html).

You could use a case sensitive collation like `utf8_bin` in the `MYCOLUMN` field:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (
    ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    // other fields...

    MYCOLUMN VARCHAR(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a column case sensitive you can use the keyword binary in the definition. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    mycolumn VARCHAR(20) BINARY
);
```

Anyway, the best solution is to use a case sensitive collation as @Reimeus says.

Comment: Yes, @Reimeus solution is better. Actually is what I use but this was the first that came to my mind.